# setting state in nested setTimeouts bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm trying to add JSX elements to a state array on a timer. So once the component is rendered, after 1200ms, a JSX element should be added to the array. 2 Seconds later, another JSX element should be added to the array.

The issue is, once the second `setBlocks` is called, the first JSX Element gets removed. Wondering if there is a way around this, or a better way to pull this off. Here is the `useEffect`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setBlocks([...blocks, serverBlock]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setBlocks([...blocks, commandBlock]);
      }, 2000);
    }, 1200);
  }, []);
```

And here is how I'm rendering the elements:

{blocks.map((block) => block)}

Comment: Change `setBlocks([...blocks, serverBlock]);` to `setBlocks(blocks => [...blocks, serverBlock]);` and the same with the second one. You have a stale closure

Comment: uhg of course. Although, it is now adding them both twice

Comment: `let id = setTimeout(...); return () => clearTimeout(id);` to fix that.

Comment: Worked! Feel free to answer and I'll mark it correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an updater function to `setBlocks` so you can change the state based on the actual previous value.

You also need to return a cleanup function from `useEffect` to cancel the timeout when the component is unmounted.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const id = setTimeout(() => {
      setBlocks(prevBlocks => [...prevBlocks, serverBlock]);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setBlocks(prevBlocks => [...prevBlocks, commandBlock]);
      }, 2000);
    }, 1200);
    return () => clearTimeout(id);
}, []);
```